# Need to understand how recursion is working in finding word permutation code sample

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have a working code sample for finding possible word permutations for mis-typed words. For example, someone types the word "gi" so the suggested words would be "go" or "hi". The find `get_nearby_letters()` and `isWord()` functions are given.

I need to understand how is `sub_words` is getting values. And since the function is called recursively how is the `char[] nearby_letters = get_nearby_letters(letters[index-1]);` program statement being reached?

I seem to be having trouble understanding how recursive functions work.

```
public List<string> nearby_words(string word)
{
    List<string> possible_words;
    char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
    possible_words = get_nearby_permutations(letters, 0);
    possible_words = possible_words.Where(x => isWord(x)).ToList();
    return possible_words;
}

public List<string> get_nearby_permutations(char[] letters, int index)
{
    List<string> permutations = new List<string>();

    if (index >= letters.Count())
    {
        permutations = new List<string> { "" };
        return permutations;
    }

    List<string> sub_words = get_nearby_permutations(letters, ++index);
    char[] nearby_letters = get_nearby_letters(letters[index-1]);

    foreach (var sub_word in sub_words)
    {
        foreach (var letter in nearby_letters)
        {
            permutations.Add(letter+sub_word);
        }
    }

    return permutations;
}
```

Comment: Recursive only means that the method is calling itself again (with a different parameter set). Recursive methods tend to StackOverflowExceptions when implemented incorrect. For example you should never call a function recursivly with a parameter set you have already used in the recursion. Otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop which then gets terminated by the StackOverfloeException.

Comment: You have a debugger. Single-step your program and observe its behavior by examining the value of variables after each step. See how it makes the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `rightget_nearby_permutations()` is recursive because it calls itself inside of the fuction. Now you are wondering **how the part after the recursive call can even be reached**.

Have a look at the parameter `index`, which is counted up each time. At the start `rightget_nearby_permutations()` will be called `index = 0`. Inside of the function you have a recursive function call with `++index`, which means the index will be counted up by one.

This goes on until the condition `index >= letters.Count()` is reached. This time there will be no recursive call and a List with one empty string will be returned. In the previously calling function this List **gets stored in the parameter `sub_words`**.

And now everything goes backwards and the **lines after the recursive call will be reached** and permutations populated.

**ProTip**: Use debugging and breakpoints to check what your code is doing.

Edit: Example of recursive call for `letters.Count()==2`:

```
Function 1
index = 0
Recursive call of    Function 2
                     index = 1
                     Recursive call of    Function 3
                                          index = 2
                                          index >= letters.Count() == true
                                          return
                     continue with f2
                     return permutations
continue with f1
return permutations
```

Comment: Actually, I would recommend _against_ using breakpoints for someone who doesn't understand recursion. Stepping in the debugger is great, but breakpoints are hit without enough context for a beginner to understand where in the recursive process they are. They can actually be disorienting rather than helpful in this specific scenario.

Comment: I have debugged the code before with break points. The part were "everything goes backwards" is what confusing me even while debugging. So the statements that come after the recursive function is called will start to get executed after the index >= letters.count (index=2) using the last value of the index before it gets incremented in the last recursive call? So it will start to execute char[] nearby_letters = get_nearby_letters(letters[index]);

Comment: with index=1 and then index=0. Is this how it works? I thought that the logic thing is to start executing the next statements in the same order the index was getting incremented which is 0 then 1.

Comment: I edited a simple sheme. Hope it gets a little clearer

Comment: Very well illustrated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> how is `sub_words` is getting values

The local variable `sub_words` receives the return value of the method call to the `get_nearby_permutations()` method.

> how is the `char[] nearby_letters = get_nearby_letters(letters[index-1]);` program statement being reached?

That program statement is executed after the previous call to `get_nearby_permutations()` returns. It works just like any program statement that follows a method call.

Stack Overflow isn't really the best place to seek help understanding recursion. It's a broad topic and typically requires some hand-holding with the student to walk them through the specifics. You should read articles such the Wikipedia article [Recursion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and the [In plain English, what is recursion?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion) Q&A on programmers.stackexchange.com.

It its core, recursion is two things:

- A method (function) that calls itself, and
- One or more termination cases, i.e. a reason for the method to *not* call itself

In your example, the method calls itself to obtain the results of the operation on the input after the current index. IMHO, it should have been written like this:

```
List<string> sub_words = get_nearby_permutations(letters, index + 1);
char[] nearby_letters = get_nearby_letters(letters[index]);
```

That would make more clear that it's not really that you want a new value for `index` in the *current* call frame of the method, but that the *next* call should use the incremented value. Incrementing the value and then subtracting it when the variable is used later in the current call frame is just confusing and inefficient.

So, you have the first part, clearly. The second part, a reason to not call itself, happens because each time it calls itself, the `index` value increases by one. Eventually, the `index` value is large enough that there are no more characters to process, and the list containing the empty string is returned instead of the method calling itself.

That is fundamentally how your recursive method works. Of course, there is a bit more to it than that. After all, the method does real work as well. But that's just regular algorithmic stuff. I.e. given the results of the recursive call, now the method will create different combinations of the current letter with the various strings returned by the recursive call.

Since the first time the method returns, it's simply returned a list with the empty string, all of the "combinations" are just the letters near the current letter. But then those letters are returned as `sub_words` values to the previous call to the method, at which point it then combines *those* values with the nearby letters to the previous letter.

In this way, the method works its way back, creating different permutations of possible words by trying all the different combinations of letters with each of the previously-determined, shorter letter combinations.

With all that in mind, your next step should be simply to step *into* the method using the debugger. You will find that with each call into the method, the `index` value increases by one, until eventually the method returns from the termination clause (i.e. the list containing the empty string), and then from there, each time you return a list, you proceed to generate a longer list based on the current letter and the previous list.

The debugger can be very informative in understanding this code. I recommend it be one of the very next things you try. :)